# How to fix Objective-c block's formatting with clang-format

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

I'm have the following code, for example:

```
    [self.service loadDataForId:@"id"
                   successBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary) {
                       NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
                   }
                     errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"%@", error);
                     }];
```

When I apply clang-format on it, it turns into:

```
    [self.service loadDataForId:@"id"
        successBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary) {
            NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
        }
        errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }];
```

As you can see, code not aligned with a colon.

If I have a code without errorBlock, clang-format works fine

```
    [self.service loadDataForId:@"id"
                   successBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary) {
                       NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);
                   }
                     errorBlock:nil];
```

I used clang-format version 8.0.0 (tags/google/stable/2019-01-18). If I used predefined styles (LLVM, Google, Chromium, Mozilla, WebKit), then I have the same problem

How to set up clang-format correct? My following settings file:

```
---
Language: ObjC
AccessModifierOffset: 0
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
AlignEscapedNewlinesLeft: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: false
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: All
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BinPackParameters: true
ColumnLimit: 0
IndentWidth: 4
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
DerivePointerBinding: false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
IndentCaseLabels: true
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: false
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
PointerBindsToType: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
IndentFunctionDeclarationAfterType: true
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
AlignOperands: true
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Never
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterStruct: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterFunction: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterObjCDeclaration: false
  BeforeCatch: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterStruct: false
  BeforeElse: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
IncludeBlocks: Merge
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^<.*\.h>'
    Priority:        -1
  - Regex:           '^<.*'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        3
```